# Why does $\left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\| \le \left\| {\left| I \right|} \right\|$, for every doubly stochastic matrix $A \in M_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\left\| {\left| . \right|} \right\|$ be a unitarily invariant matrix norm on $M_n$.

Why does $\left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\| \le \left\| {\left| I \right|} \right\|$, for every doubly stochastic matrix $A \in M_n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The result is fairly immediate if we use [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff.E2.80.93von_Neumann_theorem).  Note that permutation matrices are unitary.

Comment: Thanks,  For solve this question( by Birkhoff–von Neumann)  we need that                         $\left\| {\left| P \right|} \right\| \le \left\| {\left| I \right|} \right\|$ for any Permutation matrix $P$.Why is true?

Comment: @H.S Note that permutation matrices are unitary. What does "unitarily invariant" mean to you?

Comment: You are right. Thanks for guide.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of Omnomnomnom's answer, here is an alternative approach that doesn't require Birkhoff theorem.

It is well-known that when $A$ is doubly stochastic, its operator norm is equal to $1$ (because $1\le\rho(A)^2 \le \|A\|_2^2 = \rho(A^TA) \le \|A^TA\|_1 = 1$). So, by unitary invariance of the norm $|||\cdot|||$ in question and by singular value decomposition, you may assume that $A$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix whose largest diagonal entry is $1$. It is easy to show that such a matrix is a convex combination of at most $2n$ *diagonal real orthogonal* matrices.

Comment: It may be well known, but I didn't know it!  Neat trick, I should have thought to bring in the $1$-norm.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Your answer is nice. I prefer using Birkhoff theorem, because it results in a much cleaner solution. I give another proof here just for the sake of finding another proof.

Comment: @user1551    Thanks for your patience, The final question : Why does $\rho (A) \ge 1$?

Comment: @H.S $A$ is doubly stochastic, so $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Now $\rho(A)$ is the modulus of the largest-sized eigenvalue of $A$. Hence $\rho(A)\ge1$.

Comment: @user1551 Clarification: For doubly stochastic matrix and considering Perron-Frobenius theorem, $\rho(A)$ should be equal to 1? Please see my proof#2 attempt herein. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773629/prove-that-a-leq-i-for-every-doubly-stochastic-matrix-a-in-m-n. Do you agree with that?

Comment: @user550103 Perron-Frobenius theorem does imply that the spectral radius of a row/column/doubly stochastic matrix is $1$, but a **doubly** (rather than row- or column-) stochastic matrix is concerned, this fact follows immediately from the squeezing inequality in my answer. Perron-Frobenius theorem is not needed.