# Let $A$ is doubly stochastic , Can we say that ${\sigma _1}(A) = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ be doubly stochastic and let ${\sigma _1}(A)$ be its largest singular value.

Can we say that  ${\sigma _1}(A) = 1$?

Comment: Yes, this is already true for a stochastic matrix.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591904).

Comment: @user1551 - For solve this question , Which norm is needed?

Comment: @H.S There are many ways to answer your question. In the particular answer I linked to, the induced 1-norm (i.e. the maximum column sum norm) $\|\cdot\|_1$ is used.

Comment: @user1551 - All right, we have $\sigma_1(A)= \|A \|_2 \leq \sqrt{\|A \|_1 \|A \|_\infty}\le1 $ ,  therefore  $\sigma_1(A)\le1$. Now , why does $\sigma_1(A)=1$?

Comment: @H.S It's fully explained in my aforementioned answer. Have you read that?

Comment: @user1551 - Yes, but my questions : (1) Is ${\left\| . \right\|_1}$ unitarily invariant matrix norm? (2) Is my proof true?

Comment: @H.S (1) No, it's not. (2) If by your proof you mean your previous comment, it's incomplete. Frankly I'm very confused by what you've said. If you have really read my answer, you should know that to complete your proof, you simply need to concatenate the inequality $1\le\rho(A)\le\|A\|_2=\sigma_1(A)$ with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

**Hint:** $\sigma_1(A)^2 = \lambda_{\max}(A^TA)$. However, if $A$ is doubly stochastic, so is $A^TA$.