# Prove that $|||A||| \leq |||I|||$ for every doubly stochastic matrix $A \in M_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $|||A||| \leq |||I|||$ for every doubly stochastic matrix $A \in M_n$. Let $|||\cdot|||$  be a unitarily invariant norm on $M_n$.

---

Do you (experts) agree with these proofs? Please correct me if I am making any mistakes. Thank you so much in advance.

**Proof#1**: Utilizing [Birkhoff-Von Neumann Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem), the doubly stochastic matrix $A$ can be described by a convex combination of permutation matrices, i.e., 
$$A = \sum_i \alpha_i P_i , $$ in which $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$, $\alpha_i \geq 0 \ \forall i$, and $P_i$ are the permutation matrices (with norm $1$).

So, by utilizing the properties of the matrix norm
$$|||A||| \leq \sum_i |\alpha_i| \ \underbrace{|||P_i|||}_{=|||I|||} = |||I||| \sum_i \alpha_i = |||I|||. $$

**Proof#2**:
See herein [Why does $\left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\| \le \left\| {\left| I \right|} \right\|$, for every doubly stochastic matrix $A \in M_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591700/why-does-left-left-a-right-right-le-left-left-i-right-ri)

Comment: Seems good. For 2, you might want to justify the statement about the spectral radius by, e.g., appealing to the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: also see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591700/why-does-left-left-a-right-right-le-left-left-i-right-ri

Comment: Your second proof attempt is not quite right. First, you are proving the opposite direction of the inequality. Second, it isn't necessarily true that $|||I|||=1$ (consider the nuclear norm for instance).

Comment: oops, yes, I have made a mistake. I will remove the second proof. I agree that $|||I||| \neq 1$ unless it is an induced norm. right?